# How do I set the size of the history file in sqlite3?

Tags: sqlite

So I'm using sqlite3 on Unix,and I'd like to resize my sqlite3 command history to 999999. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: [readline init file syntax](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Readline-Init-File-Syntax.html#index-history_002dpreserve_002dpoint)

Comment: is any of that for sqlite3 though?

Answer (score -1):

> The [SQLITE_HISTORY](https://www.sqlite.org/changes.html) environment variable, if it exists, specifies
> the name of the  command-line editing history file

> To repeat the last command, just press the ↑ key, to search for older
> ones — use Ctrl+R shortcut. History search It's faster to find a query than to type it again
>
> By default, SQLite stores the history file in the user’s home directory
> and names it `.sqlite_history` It’s in plain text, so you can view it
> in your favorite [editor](https://nano-editor.org). If you prefer to save it elsewhere, specify
> the full path in the `SQLITE_HISTORY` environment variable.
> source: https://antonz.org/sqlite-history

e.g: size using [nano](https://nano-editor.org) `CTRL + Shift + 6` to mark block move cursor then `CTRL + K` to cut/del block/line

```
cd ~
nano .sqlite_history
```

or

```
split --verbose -l1000 .sqlite_history .sqlite_history.
```